# How prove this equation have more one solution $x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}=d,x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{n}=b$

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations

Let $x_{i}\in \mathbb{Z},i=1,2,\ldots,n$, and such that $1\le x_{1}\le x_{2}\le\cdots\le x_{n}$. Show that
$$\begin{cases}
x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}=d\\
x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{n}=b\\
b,d\in \mathbb{Z}
\end{cases}$$
has at most one solution $(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})$.

Comment: Do you know this to be a fact? How?

Comment: To avoid confusion shouldn't $x_i \in \Bbb{N}$

Comment: This is of no help obviously, but AM-GM can be applied and we get for a solution to exist $d^n\ge n^n\cdot b$. Which works as a filter but its not good enough.

Comment: I just now noticed that the title asks for "more one solution" while the body asks for "at most one solution", so what's the actual question?

Comment: Are you still there? any clarifications? Any thoughts on the answer I posted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$n=4$, $d=12$, $b=48$. Solutions $(1,3,4,4)$ and $(2,2,2,6)$.